# Correlate running ASP.NET Core processes with IIS end-points

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I am trying to figure out how to manage all those running ASP.NET Core processes which are hosted in an IIS reverse proxy setup; being kicked-off out-of-process by the ASP.NET Core native IIS module.

I.e. for a given IIS end-point how to find out which out-of-process ASP.NET Core process is attached to the responsible W3WP.exe reverse proxy worker process.

I noticed three variations:

1. .NET Core Framework dependent ASP.NET Core deployments (FDD) use a dotnet.exe based process; where dotnet.exe executes the specified ASP.NET Core DLL;
2. Self-contained ASP.NET Core deployments (SCD) use an < applicationname >.exe based process;
3. Full framework ASP.NET Core deployments use an < applicationname >.exe scheme as well.

Are there IIS Management PowerShell cmdlets available and/or other means to probe all running ASP.NET Core native IIS module instances?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: What do you mean by 3? I don’t think .NET Framework web apps work that way, as they are hosted by w3wp.exe directly.

Comment: @LexLi Apologies; corrected option 3 and replaced ASP.NET by ASP.NET _Core_. You are completely right that "classic" ASP.NET deployments are hosted by w3wp directly; whereas full framework ASP.NET _Core_ deployments do use an < applicationname >.exe scheme, running out-of-process from w3wp

Comment: I don't think IIS PowerShell support would step in to do anything more for ASP.NET Core. You can only use general Windows PowerShell knowledge to associate each child processes to their parent process (w3wp.exe), so as to know which child process was kicked off by which application pool. By creating individual application pools for each ASP.NET Core web apps, you can then associate the child processes with their ASP.NET Core web apps. Not easy, but it seems to be the only approach I can think of.